# Git merge feature branch WITHOUT any commit history

Tags: git, merge, version-control, rebase

say I create a new feature branch and make bunch of commits to the feature branch. My colleague also makes some commit so the master branch. How do I merge my change onto the master branch but master branch show one single commit? I have tried merging, all commits show up and it shows that I branch out. I've tried rebasing, which doesn't show me branching out but still shows all my commits. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `git merge --squash` (which forces you to also use `git commit` afterward).

#### Description

In Git, the commits *are* the history.  You can't add commits without adding history, because these are the same thing.  What you want, then, is to make a *single* commit that is *not* a merge commit that *produces the same result as if you had made an actual merge commit*.

There are multiple ways to do this, but the simplest one is to use `git merge --squash`.  This command performs what I call the "verb part", *to merge*—to perform the action of merging—but instead of making a *merge commit*, which is the adjective or noun part of a typical `git merge`, it makes an ordinary, non-merge commit.

More precisely, it *skips* the final commit, forcing you to do it yourself, using `git commit`.  The final commit, which you must make yourself like this, is an ordinary non-merge commit.  If we draw the commits the way I like to, we start with this:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- mainline
      \
       o--o--o   <-- yourbranch
```

If you make a normal everyday merge using `git checkout mainline; git merge yourbranch`, the result is:

```
...--o--o--o---M   <-- mainline
      \       /
       o--o--o   <-- yourbranch
```

which is why your three commits are now added to the main-line branch: commit `M`, the new merge, has *two* parents, one of which is the original main-line and the other being your own branch.  (Your three commits are now on *both* branches.)

If we use `git merge --squash`, however, we get this instead:

```
...--o--o--o---S   <-- mainline
      \
       o--o--o   <-- yourbranch
```

The *contents* associated with new commit `S` are *exactly the same* as the contents you would get by making commit `M`, but new commit `S` has only a single parent, so it does not associate your three commits into the main-line branch.  You are now free to *delete* your branch in the future.  When you do this, your three commits become impossible to find, and relatively soon, Git actually removes them entirely.<sup>1</sup>

Note that your branch *does not go away on its own*.  The name `yourbranch` here keeps your original three commits alive.  However, if you do more work on your branch, that's not very useful: once you've squash-merged (and committed), you should generally consider your branch "dead", and remove it once your squash-merge-commit `S` is reasonably solid.  You might want to retain it for a while, though, in case `S` turns out to be bad and you or your group choose to revert `S`: in this case, you can fix up your own branch, and then re-do the `git merge --squash` later, using the updated version of `yourbranch`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Normally, Git tries hard to make sure that apparently-deleted commits stick around for at least a month or so.  However, if you delete the branch name itself, the branch's *reflog*, which is one of the things that keeps the commits around, goes away as well.  You now rely on your `HEAD` reflog.  If you had the commits checked out in this repository, that will also keep the commits around for a month or so, but if not, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I merge my change onto the master branch but master branch show one single commit?

This is somewhat ambiguous.

A normal merge does add a single new commit, but that new commits incorporates all the commits from the "other" branch into "this" branch's history - they all become "reachable" from this branch - so the *default* output of commands like `git log` shows all of those commits, as you've observed.

If the only requirement is to see the history *without* seeing the individual commits from the "other" branch, the simplest solution is to say

```
git log --first-parent
```

This allows you to condense the view of history without actually discarding any information.  It can be useful if there might be a case down the road where you want the more fine-grained history of how the branch evolved - such as tracking down a bug.  It also makes sure that if you do more work on the "other" branch, you're still able to merge those additional changes without a lot of unnecessary hassle.

In particular, the information that's retained could be particularly important if the "other" branch has been shared with other developers - which is the most common assumption if you've ever `push`ed the "other" branch.

But sometimes the individual commits are entirely useless from a historical standpoint, and the intent is to discard them entirely (along with the branch that comprises them).  For example, maybe you commit regularly, no matter what state your code is in, inserting and removing debugging code as you go, storing states that don't build and pass tests, etc.  There are reasons such a workflow might be used, and in that case, a squash merge (or an interactive rebase in which you squash individual commits) can be desirable to produce a "clean" history.

You can try to "have your cake and eat it to", but using a `--squash` merge to create a simplified history while still keeping the original branch around for a fine-grained history.  But git will in that case lose track of the relationship between the histories, and this can easily lead to far more trouble than it's worth.

In the end it depends on the workflow you (and your team, if applicable) settle on.  Just be aware of what you're doing and *why*, because on the surface it appears that you might be asking for a sledgehammer solution to a penny nail problem, and if so you should be aware of the collateral damage.